# how to get the keys of a xmlHashTable ? (libxml2)

Tags: c, hashtable, libxml2

I am using the library libxml2 to parse an XML document. And then I saw `xmlHashTable` in this library. Is it possible to get all the keys of a `xmlHashTable`? I want to store all the keys in an array.

The XML document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?type-proto key="MIPRegistrationRequest" value="mip" ?>
<?avp-proto key="Example-AVP" value="data" ?>

<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "dictionary.dtd" [
    <!-- Any files added here need to be added to Makefile.am and
         packaging/nsis/wireshark.nsi -->

    <!ENTITY nasreq         SYSTEM "nasreq.xml">
    <!ENTITY eap            SYSTEM "eap.xml">
    <!ENTITY mobileipv4     SYSTEM "mobileipv4.xml">
    <!ENTITY chargecontrol      SYSTEM "chargecontrol.xml">
    <!ENTITY sunping        SYSTEM "sunping.xml">
    <!ENTITY TGPP           SYSTEM "TGPP.xml">
    <!ENTITY TGPP2          SYSTEM "TGPP2.xml">
    <!ENTITY sip            SYSTEM "sip.xml">
    <!ENTITY etsie2e4       SYSTEM "etsie2e4.xml">
    <!ENTITY Ericsson       SYSTEM "Ericsson.xml">
    <!ENTITY mobileipv6     SYSTEM "mobileipv6.xml">
    <!ENTITY Cisco          SYSTEM "Cisco.xml">
    <!ENTITY Starent        SYSTEM "Starent.xml">
    <!ENTITY Vodafone       SYSTEM "Vodafone.xml">
    <!ENTITY AlcatelLucent      SYSTEM "AlcatelLucent.xml">
    <!ENTITY Nokia          SYSTEM "Nokia.xml">
    <!ENTITY NokiaSolutionsAndNetworks  SYSTEM "NokiaSolutionsAndNetworks.xml">
    <!ENTITY HP         SYSTEM "HP.xml">
    <!ENTITY Oracle         SYSTEM "Oracle.xml">
    <!ENTITY Custom         SYSTEM "Custom.xml">
]>
<dictionary>
...
<dictionary>
```

I am trying to get the all the keys of the external (parsed) entities (such as nasreq, eap etc):

```
ddict_t *ddict_scan(const char* system_directory, const char* filename) 
{

    char *path = g_strconcat((const gchar*) system_directory, (const gchar*)filename, (const gchar *)'\0');
    xmlDocPtr p1 = getdoc((const char *)path);
    xmlEntitiesTablePtr ptr2 = p1->intSubset->entities;
    //to be added
}
```

The type of `xmlEntitiesTable` is a `xmlHashTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [xmlHashScan()](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-hash.html#xmlHashScan) function (and its pickier relatives), which can be used to have a user-provided [xmlHashScanner](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-hash.html#xmlHashScanner) function called back by the library for each entry in the `xmlHashTable`. The `xmlHashScanner` is given the `name` of each entry as parameter, so it should be easy to assemble a list of all the keys that way.

Comment: I added my code to show my question. Could you please give me some code to help me get the keys (for instance the content of the user-defined xmlHashScanner)? I am strugglinig with this for already two months and have never found a solution.

Comment: @BohaoLI: To give an authoritative solution, I'd have to test it. Since I only got snippets of your code, and don't do XML parsing like that of my own, I'd have to write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of my own, and it would probably be bad architecture when "dropped into" your larger solution. I'd not help you much, and probably confuse you a lot. Aside from that, I'll be going on holiday in a few hours' time, so.... sorry. :-\

Comment: It's okay, enjoy yourself! In fact, you already helped me a lot cause from two months ago I have been always wondering if there is any possibility of doing this, now that I know it's possible, I will try to find the answer by myself.

Comment: @BohaoLI: Set up a data structure to hold the key list. (Array, linked list, whatever.) Set up a callback function having the required profile for a `xmlHashScanner` that takes its `name` parameter and adds it to your data structure. Invoke `xmlHashScan` on your `xmlEntitiesTablePtr` (if I read the code snippet correctly), passing your callback function as `xmlHashScanner`. That should be about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). An easier way to get the entity declarations is to iterate the children of the DTD node:

```
xmlDtdPtr dtd = doc->intSubset;

for (xmlNodePtr child = dtd->children; child; child = child->next) {
    if (child->type == XML_ENTITY_DECL) {
        printf("%s\n", child->name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know more details (especially the code), you can look at my following code which helps me get the key list:

```
typedef struct _entities_key_list{
    xmlChar *name;
    struct _entities_key_list *next;
} entities_key_list;

static entities_key_list *head_key_list = NULL;
static entities_key_list *current_key_list = NULL;

/**
 * @brief Callback when scanning data in a hash with the simple scanner
 * @param the data in the hash
 * @param extra scanner data
 * @param the name associated
 * @return void
 */
void the_callback_function(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name){
    if(!head_key_list)
    {
        head_key_list = current_key_list = g_new(entities_key_list, 1);
        head_key_list->name = name;
        head_key_list->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        current_key_list = current_key_list->next = g_new(entities_key_list, 1);
        current_key_list->name = name;
        current_key_list->next = NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Parses the entity inforamtion in the XML document: dictionary.xml
 * @param ptr pointer to an XML document
 * @return pointer to a linked list of type entity_t
 */
entity_t *parse_entities(xmlDocPtr ptr) 
{
    xmlHashScanner ptr27 = &the_callback_function;
    xmlHashTablePtr ptr28 = (xmlHashTablePtr) ptr->intSubset->entities;
    xmlHashScan(ptr28, ptr27, NULL);
    puts("**************************************************");
    puts("let's test if I have got the great result!");
    printf("the result is: %s\n", head_key_list->name);
    printf("the result is: %s\n", head_key_list->next->name);
    puts("**************************************************");
... //code that is not interesting anymore
}
```