# the difference between void (*xmlHashScanner) and void *xmlHashScanner

Tags: c

What is the difference between `void (*xmlHashScanner)(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name)` and `void *xmlHashScanner(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name)` in C?

Why do they behave differently?

`xmlHashScanner` is a user-defined function in the library `libxml2`.

When I try to redefine this function with a little different prototype: `void *xmlHashScanner` instead of `void (*xmlHashScanner)` I have the following error:

```
error: ‘xmlHashScanner’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 void *xmlHashScanner(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name)
       ^
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:18:0,
                 from /home/solar/Bureau/parser/src/diam_dict.c:12:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/hash.h:88:16: note: previous declaration of ‘xmlHashScanner’ was here
 typedef void (*xmlHashScanner)(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name);
```

I wonder what is the difference between two of them.

Comment: Can you explain the different behaviors?

Comment: @ScottHunter I said they are different because one compiles and the other doesn't.

Comment: `void (*xmlHashScanner)()` is a pointer to a void function. `void *xmlHashScanner()` is a function returning void pointer.

Comment: @Arkadiy And what is a pointer to a void function for? The first returns what?

Comment: You are completely lost here. I see where your problem is, but the way you asked your question it cannot be answered sensibly. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for what the function is for, you could try [the docs](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-hash.html#xmlHashScanner) of the API you're using. This is a *callback declaration*. Some functions require a *function pointer* as a *parameter*. They will then "call back" your function as part of their operation. [Are you on the same course?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38700120/60281)

Comment: Please google "pointer to function in c"

Comment: A good example from the standard library is [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), which needs a pointer to a function doing the actual comparing. Check the example code on the linked site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void (*xmlHashScanner)(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name)
```

declares `xmlHashScanner` as a *pointer to a function* returning `void`, whereas

```
void *xmlHashScanner(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name)
```

declares `xmlHashScanner` as a function returning a pointer to `void`.

In both declaration and expression syntax, the unary `*` operator has lower precedence than the postfix `[]` subscript and `()` function call operators, so

```
T *a[N];     // a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];   // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *f();      // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();    // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Comment: I thought I had learnt a lot about c, but now I feel that I just discovered %0.1 of it... There is still a long way to go.

Comment: @cheater:See section 6.7 of the [latest online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C standard for a complete description of declaration syntax.  6.7.6 (Declarators) is where things get really ugly^H^H^H^H interesting.

Answer (score 3):

`void (*xmlHashScanner)(...)` is a prototype for a function pointer returning nothing (void) whereas `void *xmlHashScanner(...)` is a prototype for a function returning a void*

Answer (score 0):

So you are comparing this:

```
void *xmlHashScanner(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name);
```

with this:

```
typedef void (*xmlHashScanner)(void *payload, void *data, xmlChar *name);
```

The first is a declaration for a function, and the second one is a `typedef` (defines a type). A function and a type are vastly different things; they are used for different purposes:

- A function can be called
- A type can be used for making a variable, which can then participate in calculations

This is what your compiler means by "a different kind of symbol" - there is no context (unless by accident) where these pieces of code can do anything similar. Consider, for example, tho pieces of code - `42` and `&&`. They have nothing in common - they are two different *kinds* of things.

To understand the details of the declaration, which are a bit confusing, use the [right-left](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) rule, which is also implemented [here](http://cdecl.org).

- `typedef void (*xmlHashScanner)(whatever)` means `xmlHashScanner` type is a pointer to a function with whatever arguments returning `void`
- `void *xmlHashScanner(whatever)` means `xmlHashScanner` is a function with whatever arguments, which returns `void *`